# Ranging 500 iBeacons using one UUID

Tags: ios, range, monitoring, ibeacon

Let's say I have 500 iBeacons deployed that I want to use with one app.

Can I have one UUID for all 500 beacons and specific major and minor identifiers to each of the 500 beacons?

If so, can I monitor the region of my UUID and start ranging for the specific major and minor identifiers once the region is entered?

---

I'm confused as to what ranging actually does. Can I get the major and minor identifiers from ranging, or I will only get the distance from the device?

Comment: I edited the title of your question to better represent what your question is about. I also fixed some minor grammar in your question, as well as adding a separator for visual appeal. However, much of the information you want about can be found elsewhere, such as in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html). Also, see the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have all your beacons included in a single region defined by the UUID. It can be 500 beacons or much more: there is no upper limit. Then if you enter this region and start ranging, you'll receive a list of beacons in range, along with Major and Minor IDs. Keep in mind though that not all beacons in this region have to be in range.

I think this article we posted on Estimote Community Portal explains difference between monitoring and ranging quite well: https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203356607-What-are-region-Monitoring-and-Ranging-

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The major and minor values are unsigned short integers, so that means they can store a number no greater than 65'536 within them, so in theory you can monitor and see up to 4'294'967'296 beacons per UUID, and you can have 20 of those.

Monitoring can be done in the background, Ranging needs to be done in the foreground.

Monitoring is a low power activity, ranging I read isn't.

Monitoring can be slow to react, too slow for many, especially if your looking at region triggers, entering is ok, leaving can take 10 to 15 seconds or more. Ranging in contrast is almost immediate, and quite dependable. I tried both and gave up on relying on monitoring, you need your app to be running in foreground; ranging in an ideal world.